# Factory Method - get by ID in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, factory-pattern

I am trying to implement a factory. As I understand it, the following simple code is a factory (C#)

```
private void methodName()
{
    var result = GetTypeByName("nameOfType")
}

private AbstractClassName GetTypeByName(string nameOfType)
{
    switch(nameOfType)
    {
       case "type1":
           return new inheritedFromAbstractClass();
       case "type2":
           return new alsoInheritedFromAbstractClass();
       default:
           throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

I am sadly stuck on a .NET 2.0 project with VS2005 and as such can't use the 'var' keyword. Can any one give me any advice on how something like this was done or how it can be done in .NET 2.0.

So, a more real life example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting order");
        Console.WriteLine("Press 1 or 2");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        var order = GetOrderByIdFromFactory(s);
        order.ShippingAddress = "My House, England";
        Console.WriteLine(order.Ship());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static OrderShipment GetOrderByIdFromFactory(string s)
    {
        OrderShipment os = default(OrderShipment);
        switch (s)
        {
            case "1":
                return new FedExShipping();
                break;
            case"2":
                return  new UpsShipping();
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Not implemented");
        }
    }
}
```

My Abstract base class

```
public abstract class OrderShipment
{

    #region Properties
    public string ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    internal string Label { get; set; }
    private readonly TextWriter _text = new StringWriter();
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    internal string Ship ()
    {
        VerifyShippingData();
        GetShippingLabelFromCarrier();
        PrintLabel();
        return _text.ToString();
    }

    internal virtual void VerifyShippingData()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ShippingAddress))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Invalid Address");
        }
    }

    internal abstract void GetShippingLabelFromCarrier();

    internal virtual void PrintLabel()
    {
        _text.Write(Label);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And my 2 inheriting classes

```
public class FedExShipping : OrderShipment
{
    internal override void GetShippingLabelFromCarrier()
    {
        //ToDo perform logic
        Label = "FedEx Label Details";
    }
}

public class UpsShipping : OrderShipment
{
    internal override void GetShippingLabelFromCarrier()
    {
        //ToDo logic
        Label = "Ups Label Details";
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just declare result as the AbstractClassName. Another option would be to use an interface.

Comment: why dont you use `AbstractClassName` instead of `var`

Comment: Even the var wouldn't help you, it would infer the type exactly to `AbstractClassName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not somethign like this:

```
AbstractClassName result = GetTypeByName("nameOfType")
```

`var` keyword is not an *innovation*, it's just let's you *do not type* `AbstractClassName` (in this concrete example). So within this concrete question scenario you don't loose much using `2.0`

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a Factory is that it hides which sub-type of your abstract class is instantiated from the system. This allows you to easily switch (e.g. through config files) which sub-class should be used all over your system.

However, for this to work your Factory should expose a method to construct an instance of the abstract class. I would probably change your code:

```
private void methodName() 
{ 
    var result = GetTypeByName("nameOfType") 
}
```

to

```
public AbstractClassName Create() 
{ 
    return GetTypeByName("nameOfType") 
}
```

Comment: +1 for the create class which has led me to understand the factory class better - I have now also looked further into this and for any one else who finds this post useful, I found a page which simply yet [clearly explains the factory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use

```
AbstractClassName result = GetTypeByName("nameOfType");
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void methodName()
{
    AbstractClassName result = GetTypeByName("nameOfType")
}
```